# Trying to access data within php array

Tags: php, json, laravel

If I return this array as json:

```
$events['data']
```

I get:

```
[
    {
        "id":"3"
    }
]
```

But if I try to return the id, I get `Undefined index: id`, using this code:

```
$events['data']['id']
```

How can I access that data?

Edit: added var_dump of $events['data'] below:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(15) "299452650179381"
    ["name"]=>
    string(23) "Body of Work Exhibition"
    ["description"]=>
    string(380) "Friday 23rd May - Private view from 6-9pm. Part of Dartmouth Galleries Week.
A group show of 11 artists including Clare Cutts, Aliisa Hyslop, Janet Mitchell, Lynn Muir wooden figures, Jane Ryan OPI Kathryn O'Kell, Sarah Saunders Ceramics, Kate Glanville - Plates and Tiles, Karen James,  EllyMental Jewellery and Elvis the Kat
All work will feature bodies whether human or animal."
    ["cover"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["cover_id"]=>
      string(15) "750312108326721"
      ["source"]=>
      string(101) "https://scontent-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/t1.0-9/s720x720/1947331_750312108326721_1639418640_n.jpg"
      ["offset_y"]=>
      int(30)
      ["offset_x"]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["start_time"]=>
    string(24) "2014-05-23T18:00:00+0100"
    ["end_time"]=>
    string(24) "2014-06-12T17:00:00+0100"
  }
}
```

Comment: Closing quotes for id is missing here `['id]`

Comment: Try `var_dump($events['data'])` to get a PHP view of the array, which should make it more obvious that there's *one more level of array* there.

Comment: You have to `json_encode($events)` to do this, not `json_encode($events['data'])`

Comment: @Jenz, sorry that was a typo.

Comment: `$events['data'][0]['id']`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I get undefined offset 0.

Comment: From what you show, `$events['data'][0]['id']` *is* the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($events as $v){
$id = $v['id'];
}
```